# Capturar campo de um JSON complexo

Tags: java, json

Estou utilizando a linguagem Java, com a biblioteca org.json version 2017101 para capturar dados de um JSON. Segue JSON abaixo:

```
{query:

{"UF":"SP", "results":

{"cidades":[

{"cidade":"sao paulo", "contagem":564561}, {"cidade":"rebeirao","contagem":5212884}]}}}
```

Para pegar apenas o JSON interno "cidades", que é o que eu precisaria na minha aplicação, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
        String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(url);

        JSONObject generateJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject generateJson2 = generateJson.getJSONObject("query");
        JSONObject generateJson3 = generateJson2.getJSONObject("results");

        JSONArray jsonRates = generateJson3.getJSONArray("cidades");
```

Achei que o código ficou meio "gambiarra", existe outra forma de pegar apenas o array "cidades"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a maneira mais simples utilizando `JSONArray` é assim:

```
JSONArray jsonRates = new JSONObject(jsonString)
  .getJSONObject("query")
  .getJSONObject("results")
  .getJSONArray("cidades");
```